# Application Cache Manifest + Local Storage Size Limit

Tags: html, limit, manifest, local-storage

I'm building an application that might have heavy offline storage needs, and I was wondering if it's possible to use both an offline cache manifest (5MB) as well as localstorage (5MB) to be able to use 10MB of storage.

Note that this is an intranet application, so we have control of the devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested this in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari and all browser use for both technique a limit of 5 mb. So it's possible...

Note:
- The limit of localStorage and Offline Application Caching varies per browser.
- IE doesn't support Offline Application Caching
- In Opera and Safari you can store more than 5mb of localStorage.
- In chrome you can check size of application cache by url: chrome://appcache-internals/ and localStorage in the map localStorage.

Comment: Did you in your test used 5mb limit of both offline cache and local storage? The aim of this question is, if there is common limit for this both caches, and it is what currently is of my interest too....